# Submit multiple forms via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, form-submit

I have a while loop that repeats a form for incidents. The form run a mysql query I am attempting to use ajax to prevent redirection of the page on submit. I am trying to figure out how to pass the data which appears to not work because each form has the same class or id.

[image of the table with submit button for each row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmRFJ.png)
Form

```
<form action="status_change.php" method="post" class="ajax">
      <div class="form-group"> 
           <input type="hidden" class="form-control"  name="incidentnum" value="' . $row_aincidents['incidentnumber'] . '">
</div>
<div class="form-group"> 
<input type="hidden" class="form-control"  name="unit" value="' . $row_aincidents['unitid'] . '">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group"> 
 <input type="hidden" class="form-control"  name="status" value="3">
 </div>

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">STAMP</button>
 </form>
```

Java Script

```
      $('form.ajax').on('submit', function () {

          var that = $(this),
                  url = that.attr('action'),
                  type = that.attr('metod'),
                  data = {};

          that.find('[name]').each(function (index, value) {
              var that = $(this),
                      name = that.attr('name'),
                      value = that.val();

              data[name] = value;

          });

          $.ajax({
              url: url,
              type: type,
              data: data,
              success: function(response) {
                  console.log(response);
              }
          });
          return false;
      });
```

Comment: What is the problem? You can’t read the data server side? Are you expecting the data thru get or post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just got a few typos and errors. You need to specify the method (and you got a typo getting that form attribute). Also you are setting the method as the `type` option.

The default method for the jQuery ajax call is `get` so you won’t be getting any data server side if you expect it via `post`.

```
  $('form.ajax').on('submit', function () {

      var that = $(this),
          url = that.attr('action'),
          type = that.attr('method'),
          data = {};

      that.find('[name]').each(function (index, value) {
          var that = $(this),
              name = that.attr('name'),
              value = that.val();
          data[name] = value;
      });

      $.ajax({
          url: url,
          method: type,
          data: data,
          success: function(response) {
              console.log(response);
          }
      });

      return false;

  });
```

Also is a good practice to set which type of returning data are you expecting from the server. The default expected data type for `$.ajax` is a guess (jQuery can detect json, xml, html and a script). You can specify the expected data type using the `dataType` option.

Also is not a good practice to have inputs with the same names within the same form. In you case, as you have multiple forms, that will not be a problem.

You can read more about `$.ajax` [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).